# Pull Down Menu IOS Problems

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to implement a pull down menu and have found this one: [iOSPullDownMenu](https://github.com/BernardGatt/iOSPullDownMenu)

I have done as described to add the pull down menu to one of my views.  However, whenever I go to the page with the drop down menu the app exits saying

> [PulldownMenu setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:]: unrecognized selector seen to instance .

I am not sure how to fix this and any help would be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pulldownMenu = [[PulldownMenu alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:pulldownMenu];

    [pulldownMenu insertButton:@"Menu Item 1"];
    [pulldownMenu insertButton:@"Menu Item 2"];
    [pulldownMenu insertButton:@"Menu Item 3"];

    pulldownMenu.delegate = self;
    [pulldownMenu loadMenu];

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage
                                                    imageNamed:@"login_bg.png"]];

    CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100.0, 100.0);
    self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    self.button1.frame = frame1;
    self.button1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.button1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1Pressed:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button1];
}

-(IBAction)menuTap:(id)sender
{
    [pulldownMenu animateDropDown];
}
```

here is the error:

```
 -[PulldownMenu setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9177360

2014-01-23 13:42:47.174  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PulldownMenu  setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9177360'
```

Comment: use an [exception breakpoint](http://www.alauda.ro/2013/02/03/xcode-4-exception-breakpoints/) and post that line of code that crashes the app (_heck, post the entire method because... well... you haven't posted any code_) but one thing is sure, some object is calling some method somewhere and it seems to be a class-related issue, like maybe you were supposed to use **B** class but you are still using the default **A** class.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running on?

Comment: @user3007080 : Autolayout is iOS6+ and `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is Autolayout specific method that creates constraints for views so it won't work under iOS5-

Comment: The method it's complaining about (`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`) is documented to only exist on iOS 6+.

Comment: ok, just tested this on ios 7, no errors, but it is as if the pull down menu doesnt exist and it doesnt seem like it is recognizing my gestures.

Comment: @user3007080 : look into **iOSPullDownMenu**'s **`PulldownMenu.m`** class. It implements a method `-createConstraints` that's using Autolayout heavily and also some lines that do `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO`. well... you could comment out these lines (_but then the behavior will be unpredictable_) and you could replace the constraints with `setFrame` methods to hack around (_but this is so messy that you'd be better off simply implementing Autolayout for this viewController_)

Comment: ya thats what I initially did, but I wasnt able to get the pulldown menu to show up/work.  But now even in ios 7 im still not able to see the pull down menu.

Comment: @user3007080 : for that... I think... you need to enable Autolayout for this view (_xib of your class_) but... not sure

Comment: it was already enabled, and i tried it both with enabled and not enabled and both did not work.